# Why does a repaint only draw one line?

Tags: java, swing

I am having problem with drawing multiple lines during repaint. The code is as follows:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    Map<Device, Device> devMap = matchEncDec();
    if(devMap != null){
        Iterator<?> it = devMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<Device, Device> pair =  (Entry<Device, Device>) it.next();
            it.remove();

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.drawLine(pair.getKey().getLocationOnScreen().x + 150, pair.getKey().getLocationOnScreen().y, 
                    pair.getValue().getLocationOnScreen().x + 150, pair.getValue().getLocationOnScreen().y);

            g2d.drawLine(50, 50, 500, 550);
        }
    }
}
```

it draws line only for the last pair in the HashMap and the test line that i added.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Does matchEncDec return a new instance of the Map everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't remove the pair from the iterator.**

```
it.remove();
```

This is an un-neccesary step if it's a temporary hashmap, and it's a critical problem if it's a reused hashmap.  This removes the item from the underlying hashmap.  So if `matchEncDec()` is returning a hashmap that is being reused, you will only paint each line once because the pair will be removed from the hashmap once it gets painted.

It would be helpful to see the `matchEncDec()` method, but I would just be checking to see if you are returning a reference to the same hashmap with each call.  If that's the case, then this is definitely the problem.

Comment: If this isn't the problem, then examine the hashmap before you iterate through it to make sure it actually contains what you think it does.  It's possible it only contains one pair, or the same pair repeated over and over.  Either way, if you're still having a problem, it's in the `matchEncDec()` method.

Comment: Yes. Even when there is more than on match it draws only one line. Ok i double check the matchEncDec() method then.

Comment: Ok, the problem really was in the matchEncDec(). Apparently HashMap can't contain key duplicates :P The repaint() works fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Caspinol Yes, well, this is a fundamental behavior of a HashMap!  I'm glad we got this figured out, and you learned something in the process.  Hooray for Stack Overflow!